# Ошибка в программе с не такими уж и большими числами

Tags: pascal, freepascal

При выполнении выдавала ошибку 201, поработал с типами данных, стала выдавать ошибку 215.
Программа простая, а как и почему ошибка вылазит- не пойму! Прошу помощи! Тестирую на входных данных 0.3, 0.7, 9

```
var
n,i:integer;
p,q,x,y,otvet,v:double;

function fact(m:integer):longint;
begin
//if m<=1 then fact:=1
//else fact:=m*fact(m-1);
fact:=1;
for i:=1 to m do
fact:=fact*i;
end;

begin
write('Введите p: ');
readln (p);
write('‚Введите q: ');
readln (q);
write('Введите N: ');
readln (n);
x:=((p+q)*(p+q))/q;
y:=((p+q)*(p+q))/p;
writeln('x=',x);
writeln('y=',y);

otvet:=0;
for i:=1 to n do begin
otvet:=otvet+((x+(y/i))/fact(2*i-1));
end;
writeln('Ответ: F=',otvet:6:3);

readln;
end.
```

Comment: @koshelev вы думаете, что каждый из сидящих тут настолько хорош в Паскале, что знает в лицо каждую ошибку, выдаваемую компилятором, только лишь по ее номеру? Спасибо, конечно, за такую оценку, но все же вы нам льстите.

Comment: ну и хрен с ним. В ABCPascal работает и ладно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ прост.

Смотрим, есть выражение `fact(2*i-1)`. Максимальное значение i = n. В Вашем случае n = 9.

Поэтому считаем факториал числа 17 ( = 2*9 - 1). А он большой. Если учитывать, что `longint` - это `-2147483648..2147483647` (4 байтовое знаковое), а 17! = 355687428096000, что требует как минимум чуточку больше 6 байт, то оно никак не вместиться.

Факториал - штука коварная.

Comment: Спасибо! Будем ставить ограничения!

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка 201 - переполнение. Полученный вами результат не влазит в тот тип данных, который вы используете. Очевидно, ошибка происходит при вычислении факториала. При `n = 9` максимальный факториал, который вы вычисляете это `(2 * n - 1) = 17`. `17! = 355,687,428,096,000`, это значительно больше, чем вмещает `longint` (2 147 483 647). Дальше, ошибка 205 - это ошибка операции с плавающей точкой. Вы делите каое-то число на факториал, который принимает огромные значения и просто не влазит в разрядную сетку типа `double`. Тут есть несколько вариантов. Первый - поменять тип `double` на `extended`, это немного отсрочит появление ошибки (но при увеличении `n` она всё равно произойдёт). Второй - пересмотреть алгоритм вычисления. Возможно, вычисление "в лоб" можно заменить на [рекуррентное соотношение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0).